# System Administrator Appreciation Day BONUS!

Tags: feature-request, badges

How about on Sysadmin Appreciation Day giving registered users a free 10 rep points or something like that on ServerFault? Might be a nice little community bonus...or a badge of some kind that shows how many SAD days have passed that you've been active on (I don't know...sign in on SAD day and get a badge?)

Might be a fun idea.

Comment: It's a fun idea that should've been proposed a week ago.  You want them to get this feature up and running *today*?

Comment: @Pesto: Well, SO can be programmed in a weekend, so a badge should take thirty seconds.

Comment: No, not that day...I was kind of hoping for next year. I was just thinking about it when sitting on Serverfault and it occurred to me that only one person in the last week had mentioned it at all.

Answer (score 4):

Like Pesto said in the comments, you jumped in a little late with the suggestion for free swag.

Also, the only times I have ever seen bonus rep given out is for accounts starting out on new websites (the association bonus) so that people can at least do something on the site. You don't just give away free rep willy nilly!

**THIS IS SERIOUS BUSINESS**

If you start giving away rep on every little holiday that comes around, you're going to start lowering the value of the rep. This is absolutely unacceptable.

Comment: +1 For using the word unacceptable and not mentioning PONIES

Comment: I don't see how that's any different from the current design of reputation that seems to devalue itself by definition without any help.

Comment: Welbog: SSSSSSHHHHH!

Comment: My Dad was in a World of Warcraft guild called Serious Business. Their website header was a picture of bunnies dressed as mobsters.

Comment: @Chacha102: Your dad sounds a lot cooler than you. Will you introduce me to him?

Answer (score 2):

As much as I'd like a SAD Panda badge, I don't think we should be giving out badges for each holiday that passes. It would cheapen achievements, since all you have to do is exist on a given day. The Enthusiast/Fanatic badges are much more suitable, IMO.

Comment: Each holiday? There are other techie holidays I'm unaware of??

Comment: @bsilver: Google celebrates most of them: http://www.google.com/holidaylogos.html

Comment: Hmm...I didn't see a system admin day logo there...

Answer (score 2):

Can I get a box of donuts mailed to me for [Programmer Day](http://programmerday.info/) by Jeff et al.?

More seriously, can we have a special theme for Programmer Day like we had on Unicorn, Pony and Rainbow Day?

*Even more* seriously, I love donuts.

Comment: +1, because I love donuts, too. And unicorns, ponies, and rainbows. Also, anything else that shows up as a marshmallow in Lucky Charms.

Comment: Are you suggesting marshmallow donuts inside Lucky Charms?! Can I marry you?

Comment: @Eric: I love anything in marshmallow form.  Marshmallow Hitler, marshmallow company-wide meetings, marshmallow hemorrhoids; they'll all good!

Comment: I would be happier, in general, if more things were filled with whipped cream.

Comment: I can get on board for Marshmallow Hitler and Marshmallow Hemorrhoids but a Marshmallow Company-Wide Meeting is obscene and inappropriate.

Comment: Oh, hey Jeff. So will you be sending me that box of donuts?